# How can I send WhatsApp's image captions to email with images?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I am using Whatsapp 'Email Conversation' option that allow me to share pictures through email, but it doesn't send the caption of images.

Is there any solution so that I can send both Image + its caption to email address?

and where are caption stored in whatsapp data?
(I have root access)