# Where are the captions stored for images that are sent or recieved in WhatsApp?

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger, images, data-transfer

When sending images in WhatsApp, there is an option to add caption to it. This caption is visible on image, at the receiving end, but when this image is copied or forwarded, only image is sent? (although the selection shows image caption also selected)

Is the image caption not in the image file itself Or its stored separately somewhere locally and so that part is dropped?

How can I forward the image along with its caption?

Comment: Please add your cell phone platform (Android, iOS, etc). Unfortunately the app have some disparities between them.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-forward-an-image-with-captions-in-WhatsApp/answer/Vishnu-M-Aiea

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in Whatsapp. It should send both image and caption.

It's present both in Android and iPhone versions. Doesn't matter if you user the FORWARD ("Arrow/Forward") or the SHARE feature, both loose the original caption.

You and everyone with this problem can (and should) send a bug report thru the app by accessing the Settings panel > help > Contact us.

Answer (score 0):

> "but when this image is copied or forwarded, only image is sent":

Well, This is not true, as selected image along with conversation can be forwarded from Conversation/Chat.

**May be your WhatsApp App version is bit old? I tested this on mine(App version:2.11.432, Running on Android 4.2)**

To Answer your specific question: Below can be steps

1. Select Image along with caption that you wants to forward.
2. Choose "Arrow/Forward" Button. This will open "Select contact" screen.
3. Click "OK" when asked about forwarding to selected contact.

And this should forward image from conversation/chat along with Image's caption to intended recipient.

Comment: I have the same problem. I updated it to the latest version, yet the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

When you  re-forward follow this step:

Instead of forwarding the message directly from WhatsApp (using right Arrow on top right) use Share button -> Choose WhatsApp and add the caption again!

Answer (score -1):

This is the workaround I found: instead of *forwarding* select *share*, 
-> then select Whatsapp -> select contact or group -> type caption again on image... too much effort but will work for emergencies.

Links to similar issues reported

[How can I send WhatsApp's image captions to email with images?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/92125/how-can-i-send-whatsapps-image-captions-to-email-with-images)

http://www.androidpit.com/app/com.whatsapp/problem-in-forwarding-picture-messages-with-some-text-in-it